# Junos upgrade from 11.4R5.7 to 12.4R6.6

Tags: switch, juniper-junos

I've been trying to upgrade the Junos version on some switches and most have gone fine using;

> root@host> request system software add /var/tmp/jinstall-ex-3200-12.3R6.6-domestic-signed.tgz

However some of them show this instead of the normal "reboot immediately.."

> Done with validate on all virtual chassis members

Before returning to prompt.

I've tried rebooting the switches and looking through messages log, however I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Has anyone else experienced this or knows of a fix?

Model: EX4200-24T

Comment: You can try a couple things.  First, can you add the output for "show virtual-chassis"?  Also do you have non-stop routing/bridge, GRES, etc enabled?

Second, just a shot in the dark, try upgrading to some other version of code - like anything in 12.1.  Sometimes there are issues with upgrading to/from specific versions.  If that works, then upgrade to 12.4R6 from there.

Comment: And on the switches where the upgrades have worked, is it all the same model?  Is it all 11.4R5 to 12.4R6 upgrades?

Comment: `> show virtual-chassis 

Virtual Chassis ID: c22a.ccc2.735a
Virtual Chassis Mode: Enabled
                                           Mstr           Mixed Neighbor List
Member ID  Status   Serial No    Model     prio  Role      Mode ID  Interface
0 (FPC 0)  Prsnt    BM0212070665 ex4200-24t 128  Master*      N

Member ID for next new member: 1 (FPC 1)
`

Yeah they are all the same model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software was for the wrong model of switch.

The package was jinstall-ex-3200-12.3R6.6-domestic-signed.tgz

i.e. for a EX-3200 model.

using

root@lsw22g> show chassis hardware | match Chassis

Chassis                                BM0212070665      EX4200-24T

We can see that the firmware does not match up.

Answer (score 0):

The message itself, just means that it validated the software for all members of the VC. How many members does 'Show virtual-ch' display?
Remember, members running different versions, cannot form a virtual chassis.

Can you try the same install using the 'no-validate' suffix?

Btw, it  is possible to do NSSU on EX-series. Again, capabilities and version **must** match.

Comment: The no-validate suffix just gives no output at all and returns prompt (no version change even after reboot)

Comment: `> show virtual-chassis 

Virtual Chassis ID: c22a.ccc2.735a
Virtual Chassis Mode: Enabled
                                           Mstr           Mixed Neighbor List
Member ID  Status   Serial No    Model     prio  Role      Mode ID  Interface
0 (FPC 0)  Prsnt    BM0212070665 ex4200-24t 128  Master*      N

Member ID for next new member: 1 (FPC 1)
`